# queryfirst vs extension: store procedure with multiple params

Tags: query-first

I am currently testing vs extension "[queryfirst](https://github.com/bbsimonbb/query-first)".

Did anyone successfully used it against more than one parameter for SP0's? Currently all my testing only defines first parameter on Execute().

Here is my SQL

```
/* .sql query managed by QueryFirst add-in */ 
-- designTime - put parameter declarations and design time initialization here 
declare @PERFIL nvarchar(50)='A' 
declare @COD nvarchar(50)='01' 
-- endDesignTime 
exec WSP_CLIENTES @PERFIL, @COD
```

Or am I missig something?.. thanks

Comment: Hello and Welcome to SO! Don't forget to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here. Could you add more detail on your problem? What have you done, what errors you get?

Comment: Multiple parameters should not be an issue. Could you post the full contents of your .sql ? What database are you using ?

Comment: Using sql server 2014.. I trying to run an SP;
*Defined parameters on specific area (3 parameters)
*Executed SP successfully and saved o results
*model created ok
** Execute only accepts first parameter on list...

Comment: There's not enough information here for me to help you. QueryFirst processes .sql files (created via the template). If you show me you .sql, I might be able to tell you something.

Comment: ok.
my sql:
'
/* .sql query managed by QueryFirst add-in */


-- designTime - put parameter declarations and design time initialization here
declare (at)PERFIL nvarchar(50)='A'
declare (at)COD nvarchar(50)='01'

-- endDesignTime
exec WSP_CLIENTES (at)PERFIL,(at) COD
'

Comment: and as result my code generated:
'
        public virtual IEnumerable<WSP_CLIENTESResults> Execute(string PERFIL, IDbConnection conn)
        {
            IDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = getCommandText();
            AddAParameter(cmd, "NVarChar", "@PERFIL", PERFIL, 50);
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    yield return Create(reader);
                }
            }
        }
'
so where is my other param?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting a semicolon after each declaration, and make sure each declaration is on its own line. QueryFirst will do this for you if you let it.